# How can i use git for OpenAL Soft library?

Tags: git, clone, git-bash, telegram

I am trying to add [this](http://s6.picofile.com/file/8214157934/openal.PNG) to my project. I installed git for windows. But i do not know how to use it. How i must use this instruction?

Because of less reputation i can not add image directly to the question.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

after several hour or struggling i found that after installing [git for windows](http://git-scm.com/downloads) you must run git bash that install with git. then you can clone it by your command.